# Probability. Distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Distribution function is $$D(x)=\sum_{k=1, k\geq x}^{\infty} 2^{-k}$$.

We need to find $\mathbb{P}_D(\{14\}\cup\{15\})$ and $\mathbb{P}_D([0,5])$.

1) So I think $\mathbb{P}_D(\{14\}\cup\{15\})= \mathbb{P}_D(\{14\})+ \mathbb{P}_D(\{15\})=D(14)+D(15)$ Is it right?

2) What about $\mathbb{P}_D([0,5])$?

$\mathbb{P}_D([0,5])=D(5)-D(0)$?

is $D(0) = 0$?

Comment: Is that an increasing function of $x$?

Comment: From the sum it is not look like increasing function. This information is everything I have